# Find Standard Deviation Away From the Mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Word Problem:

> In one town, the number of pounds of sugar consumed per person per
>   year has a mean of $8$ pounds and a standard deviation of $1.7$ pounds.
>   Henry consumed $11$ pounds of sugar last year. How many standard
>   deviations from the mean is that?

The answer is: $1.76$ standard deviations above the mean, but how?

Comment: Hint: what is a $z$-score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $z={X-\mu \over \sigma}={11-8 \over 1.7}=1.76$ We have expressed the difference in terms of standard deviations.

Comment: How do I know if the standard deviation is Above or Below the mean?